# What is the URL of the "All Documents" library in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation

I am working with Sharepoint Online. In experimenting with the links panel on the left hand side of the window, I removed the links to "Documents", "Pages" and "Site Contents", expecting there to be an easy way to restore the default values if I changed my mind. But the "Add Link" dialog wants the full URL to the target location, and I can't find those values in my browser history for some reason.

What are the URLs for those locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

- For **Documents**: `https://your siteURL/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx`
- For **Site Content**: `https://your siteURL/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx`
- For **Site Pages**: `https://your siteURL/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Forms/AllPages.aspx`

Comment: Thank you. A little more experimentation also suggests `siteURL/SitePages/Forms/ByAuthor.aspx` as an option for the Site Pages link.